# findViewById returns null and also : where to define my onClick?

Tags: android, view, onclick, fragment, listener

I have an app with 3 tabs which I created using Action Bar Tabs (with ViewPager) when newing the Android Project. (As a beginner I don't know much about ViewPager or Fragment or Activity, I just used the tools in ADT. You may want to consider that when bothering to answer me :) )

My problem is: 
In the third tab there are two buttons, say B1 and B2. I want to show one Fragment(SearchForSaleFragment) when B1 clicked and another when B2 clicked.

I think I should add OnClickListener for my Buttons. 
Something like this: (?)

```
RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio32); 

rb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View view) {
                     Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),SearchForSaleFragment.class);
                     startActivity(i);
                 }
             });
```

When I put it in MainActivity.OnCreate() the rb gets the null value. 
Am I on the right path at all? If so where should I put the above code in ActivityMain?

Please consider explaining even obvious points cause I'm new and not all qualified and experienced like you guys.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
ActivityMain code:

```
package com.khoonat.khoonat2;
```

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

```
/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a {@link FragmentPagerAdapter}
 * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this
 * becomes too memory intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle(Farsi.Convert(getString(R.string.app_name_farsi)));

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
    //ff code: To make the right most tab selected at the beginning.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount()-1);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    //ff code
    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio32); 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast in main!!! =)" +rb,
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}
```

//******************************************************************** inner class
    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

```
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0){
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio32); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2: this is my Toast in main!!! =)" +rb,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG*2).show();

            return QuickCreatePropertyListingFragment.newInstance(position+1);
        }
        else if (position ==1)
            return SearchForRentFragment.newInstance(position+1);
        else 
            return SearchForSaleFragment.newInstance(position+1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0: return R.string.label_create;
        case 1:
            return R.string.label_rent;
        case 2:
            return R.string.label_sell;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

third Tab: (the commented part give NUllPointerException)

```
public class QuickCreatePropertyListingFragment extends Fragment {
public static QuickCreatePropertyListingFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber){
    QuickCreatePropertyListingFragment fragment = new QuickCreatePropertyListingFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("section_number", sectionNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quick_create_property_listing, container,false);
/*
    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) container.findViewById(R.id.radio32); 
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)" +rb,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            rb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View view) {
                     Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),SearchForSaleFragment.class);
                     startActivity(i);
                 }
             });
             */
    return rootView;

}
```

}

third tab .XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right" 
android:paddingRight="10dp">
    <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroupInTab3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >
        <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio31"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:checked="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test" />
        <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio32"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:checked="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="test" />
    </RadioGroup>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: post something useful code so that we guys identify your issue.

Comment: can you post the two first line of your on create method plz? and also post the layout corresponding to your activity

Comment: post your 3rd tab code and xml.

Comment: get hands on some simple and straight forward examples first. Don't dive into ViewPager directly before knowing Activity and fragment.

Comment: I edited and put the whole ActivityMain code there.

Comment: @ GauravGupta can you give a good example?

Comment: whats wrong in question? what's with the down vote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Problem is here: `RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio32);`
You should show which view you are getting the RadioButton, it should be something like this:

```
 View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
 RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.radio32);
```

Comment: Thanks man. You are a saver. Button being null problem is solved now. just another problem: How should I say that when the button is clicked a layout should be shown?    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),SearchForSaleFragment.class);
                     startActivity(i);   is not the right way as in my code. SearchForSaleFragment is one on my already existing fragments. Should I define a new activity in manifest?

Answer (score 1):

Change `RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) container.findViewById(R.id.radio32);` to `RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radio32);`. That should do it.